# Why does StreamWriter need to be open to access my MemoryStream?

Tags: c#, idisposable, streamwriter, memorystream

I have some test code that's preparing a `MemoryStream` that will eventually be read by an object. Here's how I *want* to write it:

```
        var manager = new LeaderboardImportManager(leaderboard);
        var columnNames = manager.ColumnNames;

        var stream = new MemoryStream();
        using (var writer = new StreamWriter(stream))
        {
            writer.WriteLine(string.Join(",", columnNames));
            foreach (var user in users)
            {
                var row = leaderboard.Metrics.Select(m => Faker.RandomNumber.Next().ToString()).ToList();
                row.Insert(0, user.UserName);
                writer.WriteLine(string.Join(",", row));
            }

            writer.Flush();
            stream.Position = 0;
        }

        return stream;
```

But when I do it that way, my stream object becomes unreadable and my test fails, so I have to do it like this:

```
        var manager = new LeaderboardImportManager(leaderboard);
        var columnNames = manager.ColumnNames;

        var stream = new MemoryStream();
        var writer = new StreamWriter(stream);

        writer.WriteLine(string.Join(",", columnNames));
        foreach (var user in users)
        {
            var row = leaderboard.Metrics.Select(m => Faker.RandomNumber.Next().ToString()).ToList();
            row.Insert(0, user.UserName);
            writer.WriteLine(string.Join(",", row));
        }

        writer.Flush();
        stream.Position = 0;
        return stream;
```

This, of course, prevents me from being able to dispose of my `StreamWriter` object, which as I understand it, should definitely be disposed of.

Why does the `StreamWriter` need to remain open if I've flushed its contents to the `MemoryStream` object already?

I can think of some very inconvenient ways to work around this, but I'd like to know why it doesn't work the way I want it, and whether or not there's something I can do to make it work that way. Any advice is appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The other answers indicate I should use the constructor that has a `leaveOpen` param and set it to true, but I dislike this because the constructor also requires a `bufferSize` argument.

However, I realized that I can get away with this just as easily:

```
        // new method body, returns byte array

        var stream = new MemoryStream();
        using (var writer = new StreamWriter(stream))
        {
            writer.WriteLine(string.Join(",", columnNames));
            foreach (var user in users)
            {
                var row = leaderboard.Metrics.Select(m => Faker.RandomNumber.Next().ToString()).ToList();
                row.Insert(0, user.UserName);
                writer.WriteLine(string.Join(",", row));
            }

            writer.Flush();
            stream.Position = 0;
        }

        return stream.ToArray();

        // consumer opens a new stream using the bytes

        using (var stream = new MemoryStream(this.GetCSVStream(leaderboard, users)))
        {
            mockFile.Setup(f => f.InputStream).Returns(stream);
            this.service.UpdateEntries(update.ID, mockFile.Object);
        }
```

Comment: If you prefer to not pass the extra arguments, you might want to use `GetBuffer` instead of `ToArray`.  `GetBuffer` returns the internal buffer directly and is simple managed memory and thus accessible even after the `MemoryStream` is disposed.  `ToArray` makes a copy of the data which may introduce performance and memory issues depending on the size of your data and your specific scenario.

Comment: Thank you, I will look into that.

Answer (score 3):

By default, the `StreamWriter` "owns" the stream it is passed and will close it when disposed. Use the constructor that has a [`leaveOpen` boolean parameter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg712853(v=vs.110).aspx). Set it to true to avoid closing the underlying `Stream` when the writer is disposed in your first example.

Comment: The constructor that takes this parameter also requires a bufferSize arg. Is that as inconvenient as it seems to be? How am I supposed to know how big it needs to be?

Comment: @samo set it to 256 for example. You need larger blocks if you write bigger chunks of data. But this is not the limit and only affects performance so don't worry.

Comment: It may bear mentioning that that particular constructor overload was only added as of .NET 4.5.  If you can't use .NET 4.5 you're out of luck.

Comment: @Samo The default buffer size is 1024.

Answer (score 2):

`using` operator calls `Dispose` method on object before exiting the operator block `{ }`.

On disposal, `StreamWriter` disposes underlying `Stream` too.

This means your `Stream` is an invalidated object before it gets returned.

Apply `using` statement only for objects created and destroyed in current scope (do not return them at least).

> Why does the StreamWriter need to remain open if I've flushed its
>   contents to the MemoryStream object already?

As @mikez mentioned, by default created `StreamWriter` "owns" the underlying stream, but you can avoid this behaviour by adding `leaveOpen = true` in constructor.

```
new StreamWriter(stream = s, encoding = Encoding.UTF8, bufferSize = 128, leaveOpen = true)
```

Answer (score 2):

`StreamWriter` automatically closes the `Stream` if you don't tell it not to.  Create it like this instead to leave the `Stream` open:

```
using (var writer = new StreamWriter(stream, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, 1024, true))
```

Alternatively, if you don't wish to pass the extra arguments, use `GetBuffer` to access `MemoryStream`'s internal buffer.  Avoid `ToArray` as this creates a copy of the data and depending on your scenario may be inefficient.

Comment: @Samo I agree but unfortunately `StreamWriter` doesn't have a constructor that lets you pass both a stream and the `leaveOpen` parameter.  1024 is the value used internally so it matches the behavior of the constructor you use in your code sample.  See http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/streamwriter.cs,62bd8ad495f57b21